# What is the @ sign in SQL used for other than parameters?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For a query which looks something like

```
select * from cus_query.ca_activity_vw@drifter
```

I imagine cus_query is the schema and the view's name is ca_activity_vw. But what is drifter ?

Comment: Standard SQL does not use the `@` at-sign at all.  Some DBMS use the `@` to indicate a remote object — it could be that the `cus_query.ca_activity_vw` is in a remote database identified by `drifter`.  You need to look in the Oracle manuals, though.

Comment: a database link

Comment: Great info. Thanks. I ran the query from another database connection which had the privileges and that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quote the Oracle documentation:

> If the identifier names an object on a remote database, you must reference it with its remote name. The syntax is:
>
> ```
>        simple_identifier_name@link_to_remote_database
> ```
>
> If the identifier is declared in a PL/SQL unit on a remote database, you must reference it with its qualified remote name. The syntax is:
>
> ```
>        unit_name.simple_identifier_name@link_to_remote_database
> ```

From this page : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS99945

Comment: Great info. Thanks. I ran the query from another database connection which had the privileges and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

`drifter` is a so-called [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083) - it allows to transparently query tables that reside on a different database (usually Oracle, but possibly some other RDBMS, e.g. via [Database gateway](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/toc.htm)).

To see the definition for the database link, you can use this query (this requires DBA privileges):

```
select * from dba_db_links
```

Comment: Great info. Thanks. I ran the query from another database connection which had the privileges and that worked.